# Top speed of a railgun

Tags: electromagnetism, energy

Ive asked this question before but i wrote it in a very confusing manner so ill do it again but in more qualitative terms:

The "classical railgun" i first learned about (mag field is produced by a permanent magnet) has a top speed because as the slug accelerates, the time derivative of mag flux increases continuously until induced voltage = voltage of battery.

However what about when the mag field is produced by the current running through the rails themselves? ( like the us navy railgun) It seems that there would never be a top speed because as current tends toward 0, so does mag flux and therefore the voltage created by faraday's law would never quite reach the battery voltage and acceleration will continue to exist. Is this true??

Note: for the purpose of this question please assume the only force involved is the lorentz force, do not include friction.

Thank you

Comment: They don't use batteries for the Navy rail gun.  They use a capacitor bank.

Comment: @DavidWhite I know that but I'm trying to simplify my model as much as possible and using capacitors would complicate things too far.this being said, please assume a battery was used for the railgun for the purpose of this question

Comment: If you are shooting the rail gun in air, the top speed is the speed at which atmospheric friction melts the projectile.  Are you asking about the ultimate top speed without this constraint?

Comment: @DavidWhite yes, assume the only force on the projectile is the lorentz force

Comment: I don't know the answer, but you may want to include this condition in your original posting.

Comment: @DavidWhite hello, i cant seem to properly access the chat, if you have a helpful answer please write it in the comments